# How the ES6 map function creating array of object in JSX

Tags: reactjs

Please bear with my limited knowledge of React as I have started learning it only recently.

I wrote this code snippet in a react component -

```
this.headerArr= this.props.headerList.map((item,index)=>(
<th key={index}>
{item}
</th>
));
```

The idea is to loop through each element of the 'headerList' array and create a  element out of it.

If I write the same above code in a normal javascript environment (e.g. chrome devtools console) it won't even compile (because of the 'th' flags).

How does the same map function creates an array of objects and returns to  'headerArr'. The generated array looks to have mysterious elements -

```
Object {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "th", key: "1", ref: null, props: Object, …}
```

What exactly is happening?
I could not find a reference in react documentation.

Comment: This is [tag:jsx], not [tag:reactjs] (although they typically go hand in hand). The relevant documentation you need is at https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects .

Comment: Jsx is transpiled to a simple function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are mixing HTML (the th-tags) and JavaScript. Usually this is not possible in javascript as you realised. React uses an extended Syntax called **JSX** ([details](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)) that enables you to mix HTML and JS.

React automatically calls React.createElement on each of the JSX tags. This creates special objects (of the type React.element) that have all the typical properties a React object has (e.g. a key, ref, props etc.) ([some more details](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)). Usually this wanted behavior, e.g. if you re-use this.headerArr in a render function. For example `render() return( <div>{this.headerArr}</div> )`

Comment: To add to this answer, I would say that the HTML(JSX) elements returned from above are processed as React.createElement and this is what returns the above object mentioned in the question

Comment: Is there something special processing for 'map' in react world? e.g. You wont get the similar behavior if you put the code in a for loop instead of map.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thanks for the improvement, I added that.

Comment: @ShibasisSengupta: This has nothing to do with map. You can use foreach as well, as shown here: https://codesandbox.io/s/543q98246x How do you process the array with foreach so that it does not work? Foreach does not work exactly like map, so maybe you have made a mistake there?